# Android - Parse.com retrieve the whole object of a query and display in ArrayList

Tags: android, parse-platform

In the following code I search HighScore class for the best time results ordered by ascending.
So I'm getting list of best results. 
What I having a difficulty is to add the name and the school name to of each time result to the list.(please see the attached images)

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // Override this method to do custom remote calls
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Gets the current list of bestTime in sorted order
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestsTopRecords");
        query.orderByAscending("bestTime");

        try {
            results = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        HighScoreTable.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HighScoreTable.this, "",
                "Loading...", true);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Put the list of results into the list view
        ArrayAdapter<Double> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(HighScoreTable.this,R.layout.todo_row);
        for (ParseObject object : results) {
            adapter.add((Double) object.get("bestTime"));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        HighScoreTable.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score_table);

    TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

[image: How I would like it to look like]

[image: ScreenShot of the Prase.com DataBase]

Comment: Did you try something like making your ArrayAdapter of your own type(instead of double), containing the double and 2 strings(name & city), then in the for add the recent created yourTypeObject(double and 2 strings) object containing the 3 values you  need ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably the simplest hack to do this.

Use `String` instead of `Double` and do this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HighScoreTable.this,R.layout.todo_row);
for (ParseObject object : results) {
    adapter.add((Double) object.get("bestTime") + " " + object.getString("Name") + " " + object.getString("SchoolAndCity"));
}
```